# Functions not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know why this work:

```
var currentObj = document.getElementById(id);
currentObj.className = "";
currentObj.className = "offButton";
```

And this do not work:

```
$(id).attr("class", "offbutton");
```

Do I forgot something ?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried $(id).addClass("onbutton") and $(id).html("ajouter au carnet") ?

Comment: do you have jquery plugin included?

Comment: Yes for sure for jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `id` is just the string, then jQuery is looking for a html tag of that type rather than the id.  For example, if `id` is 'foo' then the jQuery selector is looking for an element tag of `foo` rather than the id.

Try changing your jQuery selectors to: `$('#' + id)`  This will modify the id string so that jQuery knows to search for the element id.

Comment: Aie Aie Aie... Just forget it! :( Lost like 30 min on it. Thanks!